# What is an EngD degree?

Tags: computer-science

What is the purpose of an EngD degree ([for example of Data Engineering](https://www.manchester.ac.uk/study/postgraduate-research/programmes/list/11761/engd-data-engineering/)) and what are its advantages over a PhD?

Comment: There is probably little advantage over a PhD. And maybe some disadvantages depending on the actual nature of the degree. In the US there are some "doctorates" not considered "research doctorates" and these have disadvantages. I can't comment about UK usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information [provided on Manchester's website](https://www.manchester.ac.uk/study/postgraduate-research/programmes/types/) the primary difference between PhD and EngD would appear to be that the EngD contains a formal taught component. I suggest you contact the university for more details about exactly what is involved in each case.

Whether or not you see the EngD as advantageous seems likely to depend entirely on your personal circumstances. From a future employer's perspective, I doubt the choice of EngD or PhD matters: they are likely to be far more interested in what you did than which program you enrolled in. The University of Manchester has an excellent reputation, so any degree from them is likely to be taken seriously.